# chromeless is not saving image in correct location

Tags: chromeless

[OSX] [node 8.4.0] [chromeless 1.3.0]

I am trying to implement a test using chromeless.  I am running the sample in a local instance, with one change of specifying the imagePath to save the image. It is running and saving an image however the image is being saved in the default location still. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? My desire is to save the image relative to the directory the test was executed in.

Modified line below.

```
.screenshot({ filePath: './images/test1.png'} );
```

As I said it all runs but the image is still saved in the following location

```
/var/folders/r1/4xfjz/T/cjavyrbo70000kk.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a known problem. See https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless/issues/282